# Select data from different table based on WHEN THEN ELSE Postgressql

Tags: postgresql

I am using a case statement to select rows of data from a table based on the count of rows from another table. Please check the below query.

```
select case 
        when
        (select count(*) from table1 where table1.objectid = '0000016') > 0
        then 
        select * from table2 where table2.partner = "12345"
        else
        select * from table2 where table2.partner = "67890"
        end
```

It's executing the when condition but while selecting data from table 2 throwing error as `ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"`

I'm playing with another example, in this case, its returning output correctly based on when condition

```
select case 
        when
        (select count(*) from table1 where table1.objectid = '0000000016') > 0
        then 
         'data available'
        else
        'data not available'
        end as output
```

Q:

1. does select statement allowed inside THEN block ?
2. how can i write postgres query based on count of rows from one table and select data
   based on count results .

Comment: A CASE expressions returns a **single** value (e.g. 12345). It can not return multiple rows and columns

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name . is there any way to achieve this one ?

Answer (score 2):

A SQL CASE *expression* (not a "statement") returns a single value (e.g. `42`). It can't return multiple rows and columns.

One way to achieve what you want is to use a UNION where each part is only run depending on the rowcount of the first query. To avoid running the count twice you can use a common table expression:

```
with t1_count (numrows) as (
  select count(*) 
  from table1 
  where table1.objectid = '0000016'
)
select * 
from table2 
where table2.partner = '12345'
  and (select numrows from t1_count) > 0
union all
select * 
from table2 
where table2.partner = '67890'
  and (select numrows from t1_count) <= 0
```

Another option is to use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause:

```
with t1_count (numrows) as (
  select count(*) 
  from table1 
  where table1.objectid = '0000016'
)
select table2.*
from table2 
  cross join t1_count c 
where table2.partner = case  
                         when c.numrows > 0 then '12345'
                         else '67890'
                       end
```

The count query could be integrated into CASE expression directly:

```
select *
from table2 
where table2.partner = case  
                         when (select count(*) from table1 where table1.objectid = '0000016') > 0 then '12345'
                         else '67890'
                       end
```